# react JS mapping through an object

Tags: reactjs

I have an API that's returning me the categories and subcategories of 6 different stores the list might change between stores i want to map thru all the keys and values without having to specify what key i want (ex data.Baby, Baby Healthcare) i tried object.enteries

```
function FetchedData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();



 const getApiData = async () => {
 const response = await fetch(
   `https://api/admin_stats`      
  ).then((response) => response.json());
 setData(response);
};

useEffect(() => {
 getApiData();
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

However i kept getting the error '
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.entries ()'

this is the data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial default value for `data` is `undefined`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

So on the first render this will fail with that exact error:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
```

You can set the initial value to an empty object:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

Or perhaps not perform the operation at all if `data` is `null` or `undefined`:

```
if (data) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}
```